# Method invocation does not supply scalar context... seems strange

Tags: perl

This behavior isn't Math::BigInt specific, but the following code breaks on the last line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $a = Math::BigInt->bone;
my $b = Math::BigInt->bone;

print ($a+$b)->bfac;
```

This code, however, works fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $a = Math::BigInt->bone;
my $b = Math::BigInt->bone;

print scalar($a+$b)->bfac;
```

My question is this... why isn't scalar context imposed automatically on the left argument of "->"? AFAIK, "->" only works on scalars and (exceptionally) on typeglobs.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. I should have read the warning more carefully... Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need one more set of parens,

```
print (($a+$b)->bfac);
```

as your code is interpreted as,

```
(print ($a+$b))->bfac;
```

and warnings also gave you `print (...) interpreted as function ..`

Answer (score 7):

Need a `+` so it's not interpreted as arguments to `print`.

```
print +($a+$b)->bfac;
```